# How to get tooltip text string width in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, text, width, tooltip

I have the following lines to get a tooltip text for a JList item :

```
JList aList=new JList(aData)
{
  public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent evt)  // This method is called as the cursor moves within the list.
  {
    String tooltipText="Some tooltip";
    int tooltipWidth= ?
    return tooltipText;
  }
}
```

Inside getToolTipText(), how do I get the tooltipText width?

Comment: *"how do I get the tooltipText width?"*  Why do you need it?

Comment: I form my tooltip in html like this : "<html>first line<Br>========<Br>second line</html>", I want the separator line "=====" to match the length of the first line, so it can look nicer, that's why I need the width of the first line in order to decide how many "="'s to put into the separator line.

Comment: It seems it needs either an underline beneath the `first line`, or an `<hr>`.  Either way it can be further tweaked using CSS.  You might also look to limit the width using CSS, rather than use hard line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I form my tooltip in html like this : `"<html>first line<Br>========<Br>second line</html>"`, I want the separator line `"====="` to match the length of the first line, so it can look nicer, ..

Consider alternatives 2 & 3, both of which require no calculation and look better than the 'row of equals signs'.

[image: HTML ToolTip]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class HtmlToolTip {

    HtmlToolTip() {
        String attempt1 = "<html>first line 1<Br>========<Br>second line</html>";
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(attempt1);
        label1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        String attempt2 = "<html><u>first line 2</u><br>second line</html>";
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(attempt2);
        label2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        String attempt3 = "<html>first line 3<hr>second line</html>";
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(attempt3);
        label3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING,5,5));
        p.add(label1);
        p.add(label2);
        p.add(label3);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new HtmlToolTip();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent ! I finally chose <Hr>, sometimes it helps to ask "Why do you want to do that ?" Thanks !

Comment: *"chose `<Hr>`"  A sound choice it was, too.  I preferred that to the underline.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FontMetrics` to determine the size of some text.

```
FontMetrics metrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(font);
int adv = metrics.stringWidth(text);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html

To find the used font you can query the `LookAndFeel` you are using

```
UIDefaults uidefs = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
Font font = uidefs.getFont("ToolTip.font");
System.out.println(font);
// prints: FontUIResource[family=Dialog,name=Dialog,style=plain,size=12]
```

To know the keys you can use ("ToolTip.font" here), you can check the documentation of the default LookAndFeels in Swing, for example Nimbus:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary

Comment: Thanks for the info. But in my case, how to get the "graphics" instance inside the getToolTipText() method, that's where I'm having trouble !

Comment: Inside a `JComponent` you have the `getGraphics()` method. I think your method of creating a `Graphics` is more flexible (it works where a graphics-object is not available), but using the graphics of the component should be a bit more efficient since it doesn't have to create a new image an graphics object

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer, I figured it out, here is what I did :

```
UIDefaults uidefs=UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
Font font=uidefs.getFont("ToolTip.font");
GraphicsEnvironment ge=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Graphics2D g2d=ge.createGraphics(new BufferedImage(1,1,1));
FontMetrics fontMetrics=g2d.getFontMetrics();
Top_Line_Width=fontMetrics.stringWidth("Toptip text");
```